# Upload image to firebase using react-native-image-picker

Tags: javascript, firebase, upload, react-native, firebase-storage

I’ve been trying to upload an image using firebase, React Native and react-native-image-picker.

The data I get from the image picker is in base64 format and I don’t know how to actually upload it to my firebase storage because when I execute the following line :

```
var imageRef = storageRef.child("images/usersImages/" + global.userID + ".jpg")
uploadTask = imageRef.put(global.imageToUpload)
```

Nothing is executed after. Even if I put an alert right after.
My « file » variable contains that : `'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data`

I’ve also tried to put only the response.data but it’s not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read last [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html), Firebase doesn't support uploading images as binaries from `react-native`. However, you can store the base64 encoded image directly in firebase. It would be like storing any other string in firebase. There is a limit of `less than 10 MB` though while storing image directly on firebase like this.