# React-native Firebase storage upload using putString call

Tags: firebase, upload, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm setting up this thread in order to clarify, whether firebase storage *putString* method **does** or **does not** work in React-native.

From what I've searched there is currently no way to upload File or Blob types to Firebase Storage using *put* method.

> React Native does not support the File and Blob types, so Firebase Storage uploads will not work in this environment. File downloads do work however.

SOURCE: [The Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/search?updated-max=2016-07-06T15:18:00-07:00&max-results=1&start=1&by-date=false&m=1)

Thus this call

```
firebase.storage().ref()
.child(userID)
.put(new File(['this is a small amount of data'], 'sample-text.txt', { type: "text/plain" }), { type: "text/plain" })
.then(p => {console.log(p)})
.catch(p => {console.log(p)})
```

does not work and ends up with response

> code : "storage/unknown" message : "Firebase Storage: An unknown error
>   occurred, please check the error payload for server response." name :
>   "FirebaseError" **serverResponse** : "**Multipart body does not contain 2 or
>   3 parts.**"

Nevertheless there is another option to upload data to Firebase Storage, using Firebase storage putString method. Which works with plain string. But even if I use this method to upload. I'm getting the same server reponse as before.

```
firebase.storage()
.ref()
.child(userID)
.putString('string')
.then(p => {console.log(p)})
.catch(p => {console.log(p)});
```

Bu from what I've learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739002/upload-image-to-firebase-using-react-native-image-picker). The *putString* way **should** work.

What am I doing wrong? The code works fine for me in React. Whenever I paste to React-native. It stops working.

Comment: Try [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/rn-firebase-storage-upload-sample), the library makes it possible to upload file in React Native. It also provides a [sample app](https://github.com/wkh237/rn-firebase-storage-upload-sample)

Comment: I ended up trying both react-native-fetch-blob and react-native-firestack. I wasn't able to make either of those work ..

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/react$20native/firebase-talk/Uo8E7pJJ30U/47jzoHPyBAAJ

Firebase Storage is currently not supported in React Native

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) as Ven commented before, and I was able to make it work, try using this snippet from the [index file](https://github.com/wkh237/rn-firebase-storage-upload-sample/blob/master/index.common.js) in the example:

1) Before class declaration:

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;
```

2) Inside the storing method:

```js
let filePath = 'YOUR/FILE/PATH';
let fileName = 'file_name.jpg';
let rnfbURI = RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath);
// create Blob from file path
Blob
.build(rnfbURI, { type : 'image/png;'})
.then((blob) => {
  // upload image using Firebase SDK
  firebase.storage()
    .ref('images')
    .child(fileName)
    .put(blob, { contentType : 'image/jpg' })
    .then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');
      console.log(snapshot.metadata);
      var url = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
      console.log('File available at', url);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Upload failed:', error);
    });
```

Comment: hi, i am using image picker for picking image from my phone .image picker provide the response  :{height: 33, origURL: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD&ext=JPG", longitude: -17.54892833333333, fileName: "IMG_0003.JPG", uri: "file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/…temfiles/ADC7B1EA-93A0-4A25-B7CA-342BE3EF58BE.jpg", …} ,but RNFetchBlob.wrap() only upload origURL not uri, actually i want to upload image using either data or uri because i need to reduce the image size before uploading. Please help me